# What is the difference between a request and a command?

Tags: network-programming

Just a simple question:
what is the difference between a request and a command in protocols like HTML or SMTP?
Can it be that requests await a response?
Or that one is from the client side and the other from the server side?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most succinctly a request may encompass multiple commands.

Ex Http request contains many headers

Comment: @Jay Can you give an example in smtp?

Comment: Tried, let me know is that's not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to http, smtp requests can contain multiple commands e.g. the TLS command to enabled encryption

E.g. HELO, BYE

Ftp is similar to Smtp, where a single connection (request) exchanges multiple commands (PASV... EXIT) before the connection is closed.

The main difference is the request response for http can usually be visualized as 1 request to 1 response however when you look at how the TLS encryption is applied over http you then see similar commands being exchanged between client and server before the final response is returned to the client.

In short http separates the noise of the commands by encompassing them into the header portions of the request and response.

An example of http commands without encryption would be chucked transfer encoding where the server send a part of the response after the headers in chunks which must be put back together at the client side.